# HTML/CSS: Label & Input Forms Alignment

Tags: html, css

How I could align my "message" text to the top because right now it's placed at the bottom.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/WX58z/1096/

```
<div class="block">
   <label>Message</label>
   <textarea name="Message" rows="4" id="Message" style="width:300px;"> 
   </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simply the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property:

```
.block label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`vertical-align`** property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) to change the alignment of the text:

```css
.block label {
     display: inline-block; 
     width: 140px; 
     text-align: right; 
     vertical-align: top; /*HERE*/
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="Name" />
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="block">
    <label>Message</label>
<textarea name="Message" rows="4" id="Message2" style="width:300px;"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.block label {
     display: inline-block; width: 140px; text-align: right; vertical-align:top;
}
```

Use `vertical-align: top;`

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to your label tag: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brLLupnw/)

Comment: how can i also have a bit of gap between each labels?

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to this:

```
.block label {
     display: inline-block; width: 140px; text-align: right; vertical-align:top;
}
```